# Taylor Expansion Multivariate analysis

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I would like to get some theoretical explanation on first order taylor expansion and second order taylor expansion in functions with more than one unknown. Why do we use it for multivariate analysis? I know that taylor expansion is used for estimation of a function. I know the steps of taylor expansion in multivariate analysis but never understand the reason behind it.

Comment: You approximate a surface by the tangent plane instead of   approximating a curve by its tangent. This is first order.

Comment: is the second order a more accurate estimation where the plane curve according to the function?

Comment: Whatever the dimension (1D,2D,..,nD) could be, second order approximates better (locally) than first order.